# Como fazer Group By com um campo de Soma

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, firebird

Como faço Group By com um campo que não venha de uma tabela, um campo de soma, nesse caso quero agrupar o saida_qtde, como faço?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: transforme isso numa subquery e vai conseguir fazer o group, assim por exemplo `select saida_qtde from (select ...... sum(qtde) saida_qtde, .....) sub group by saida_qtde`  ali entre parênteses coloca a query que já tem

Comment: uma dica, quando postar uma pergunta evite por imagens de código, coloque o código direto na pergunta que fica melhor para visualizar :)

Comment: Por favor clique em **[edit]** e coloque o código como texto. Colocá-lo como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052).

Comment: Bom também informar apenas o SGBD envolvido , mui raramente um problema envolve quatro ambientes ...

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde Marcos!

Essa `sum(qtde) saida_qtde` da linha 25 está em uma subquery que alimenta a declaração da linha 9. Tenta colocar ao final do código um `GROUP BY 9` ou `GROUP BY saida_qtde`.

Creio que a querie vai pedir para agrupar outras colunas também.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).